# How would you differentiate between "humanoid" species and animal-like species in terms of names?

Tags: fantasy-races, species

Basically I have multiple humanoid species (like elves, dwarves, etc) that are totally made up, and I also have animal species, like cats and dogs animals. Is there something I could call all my humanoid species, other than humans? (Because humans don't exist and I don't want to repeat "the elves, the dwarves, the nymphs, the witches, etc. etc. etc" all the time.) Is "sapients" or "anthros" good enough?

Comment: welcome to worldbuilding. What you call something and what is a good name for something is totally a matter of opinion, and as such not a good fit here, where we prefer measurable answers. More info in the [help]

Comment: Why would you call them humans if they're not humans? To me this isn't that different from dog breeds, as you won't call a pitbull a poodle and vice versa. Referring to them by the name of their kind is unavoidable if there is more than one humanoid species in the location, unless they have names (there could be synonyms like "person" to humans, but that is entirely up to you to decide).

Comment: "Humanoids" or "anthros" might work, or you could just call them "people". OTOH, there is an (arguably) factually correct, non-opinionated answer: [sophonts](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/sophont). (Incidentally, I believe this is a duplicate question...)

Comment: @Matthew People would be simplest & best. "Sophonts" is the sort term a xenobiologist might use. This is a fantasy world. Traditionally we humans divide life into people or persons and animals (which are unlike us & therefore non-human -- rather snobbish really).

Comment: @L.Dutch-ReinstateMonica You wrote "where we prefer measurable answer." What metric is used to discern the aforementioned measurable answers?

Comment: @a4android, it's either intrinsic in the question or defined by the OP. But when every answer is equally valid, per our [help], the question doesn't belong here.

Comment: @a4android, I'm used to seeing "sophonts" used much as one might use "gentlebeings"... but admittedly, usually in science fiction. I agree, it feels somewhat out of place in fantasy. (FWIW, the book I'm writing — which, in fairness, is closest to "modern fantasy" — uses "people".) Relatedly, I prefer "beasts" over "animals". Humans *are* animals, but we aren't *beasts*. (Well, most of the time .)